# If $f=u+iv$ is an entire function such that $u^2\geq v^2,$ then $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analyticity

Let $f=u+iv$ be an entire function such that $u^2(z) \geq v^2(z), \forall z \in  \mathbb{C}.$ Could anyone advise me how to prove $f \equiv$ constant $?$ Hints will suffice. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

let $g(z)=f(z)-2i$, we have $|g(z)|\geq 1$ for all $z\in \Bbb C$, now let $h(z)=\dfrac{1}{g(z)}$, $h$ is entire and bounded hence it is constant.

(the inequality):
$|g(z)|^2=u^2(z)+v^2(z)-4v(z)+4\geq 2v^2(z)-4v(z)+4=2(v(z)-1)^2+2\geq 1$

Comment: You mean, $|g(z)|\geqslant\sqrt2$...

Comment: $\sqrt2\geq 1$....

Comment: While the strength of the bound is immaterial to your argument, it does seem odd that you use $2(v^2+1)^2+2\geq 1$ rather than $\geq 2$.

Comment: @Alexy How do you arrive at $|g|\geqslant1$?

Comment: @Did: The solution by Hamou is self-explanatory.

Comment: @Did $?\geq 2$ or $1$ or $0.5$ or $0.1$ all this constants are working. The aim is to show that $g$ is bounded.

Comment: You are playing with words. Do you seriously think I am unable to see that if $|g|\geqslant\sqrt2$ then $|g|\geqslant1$? Then this conversation is useless.

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo No it was not before the added explanation.

Comment: @Did: You can look at the edit history of Hamou's solution. Anyways, his solution is awesome!

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo ?? I did look at the edit history. Why are you mentioning it?

Comment: The added explanation to why $|g(z)|$ is bounded is good but not necessary because the solution is already clear enough for me.

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo So now you are explaining why it is NOT necessary to look at the edit history? Odd.

Answer (score 6):

Observe that $f^2 = (u+iv)(u + iv) = (u^2 - v^2) + i(2uv)$. Since $f^2$ is entire, $u^2 - v^2$ is harmonic. Thus $u^2 - v^2$ is a nonnegative harmonic function.

Answer (score 4):

$$
u^2-v^2=\mathrm{Re}\,f^2\ge 0,
$$
but the function $g=f^2+1$ also entire, and 
$$
\lvert g\rvert=\lvert\, f^2+1\rvert\ge\mathrm{Re}\,(\,f^2+1) \ge 1.
$$
Hence 
$$
h=\frac{1}{g},
$$
entire and bounded.

Answer (score 3):

There did not exists $z_0 ,z_1\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z_0) =i$ and $f(z_1 )=2i$ and hence by Little Picard theorem $f$ must be constant.

Answer (score -1):

Express $f$ in polar coordinates, $f(z)=re^{iϕ}$ Then the inequality implies that ϕ is restricted to the interval $[0,π/4]$.